# Remove columns from Dataframe that all have one value (more efficient)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have following dataframe:

```
   /*
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
|a        |b       |      c   |d       |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
|      bob|      -1|         5|      -1|
|    alice|      -1|        -1|      -1|
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
*/
```

I want to remove columns which only have `-1` in all rows (in this case `b` and `d`). I found a solution but when I run my job I found out it was very inefficient:

```
private def removeEmptyColumns(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val types = List("IntegerType", "DoubleType", "LongType")
    val dTypes: Array[(String, String)] = df.dtypes
    dTypes.foldLeft(df)((d, t) => {
      val colType = t._2
      val colName = t._1
      if (types.contains(colType)) {
        if (colType.equals("IntegerType")) {
          if (d.select(colName).filter(col(colName) =!= -1).take(1).length == 0) d.drop(colName)
          else d
        } else if (colType.equals("DoubleType")) {
          if (d.select(colName).filter(col(colName) =!= -1.0).take(1).length == 0) d.drop(colName)
          else d
        } else {
          if (d.select(colName).filter(col(colName) =!= -1).take(1).length == 0) d.drop(colName)
          else d
        }
      } else {
        d
      }
    })
  }
```

Is there a better solution or way to improve my existing code?

(I think this line `val count = d.select(colName).distinct.count` is the bottleneck)

I am using Spark 2.2 atm.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of counting number of distinct values try to check if there exist any other value that is not `-1`

```
d.select(colName).filter(_ != -1).take(1).length == 0
```

---

Another approach

Instead of going through the dataframe n times (once for each column) you can try to collect statistics all at once

```
val summary = d.agg(
      max(col1).as(s"${col1}_max"), min(col1).as(s"${col1}_min")), 
      max(col2).as(s"${col1}_max"), min(col2).as(s"${col2}_min")), 
       ...)
      .first
```

Then compare if `min` and `max` value for the column is the same `-1`

Comment: thanks ! I edited my question, but the piece of code is still very inefficient imo. I have a job that runs approx +- 2min without this code, and with +- 20 min.

Comment: I've added another idea for you to try. If you have a lot of columns it can be helpful to collect statistics all at once instead of going through all data once for each colunm